# Excel cell size limitation-causing macro to fail

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am developing macro in which i am expecting string such as (present in text file):

```
QUALAPP@QUALAPPC@GENRESOUS@NOMAPP@NOMAGENCE@PRENOMAPP@ADR1APP@ADR2APP~
ADR3APP@ADR4APP@VILLEAPP@CPAPP@PAYSAPP@TELAPP@NUMCONTRAT@DATEEFFCTR~
```

in which each field is delimited by `@` and each record is delimited by `~` to be in tabular format.

Such as each field will be in consecutive cell and new record start in new row.
I have macro which currently requires copying data in one cell. But as string size increases beyond some limit I am unable to paste it. So, please provide other easy option.

Comment: Can you post your text file reading code? Because even if the string grows large, I think 2 billion char limit should be sufficient ....

Comment: @Pankaj I donot  have code issue- .the issue is when i paste string from text  file which is very huge in one cell

Comment: Then what is the issue? From your description, it looks like you have some paste related issue.

Comment: [Read this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx). The max char limit for a cell is 32767.

Comment: Do you need all the text file rows in one cell in Excel?

Comment: Thank you everyone.I resolved the problem .I was trying to get my huge data from text file in input string  for macro through one cell but it seems impossible as limit is 32767.So i pasted text file contents in  excel and excel pasted in first cell of each row .Then i formed a consolidated string by extracting contents of each rows first cell through code.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the string exceeds the capacitiy of a single cell, then read the data in one character at a time and parse the data into fields as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the string to a variable (let's call it "my_var") and then

```
arr_1 = Split(my_var, "~", -1, vbTextCompare)

For x = LBound(arr_1,1) to UBound(arr_1,1)
  activecell = arr_1(x)
  activecell.offset(1,0).select
Next
```

this creates an array and each element is one of your records; it then places each record in a new row.  You could then go back through and split each row based on "@" and place the split data in adjacent columns.